# Java Lambda, Stream and Filter

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have an array [ 1,2,3,4,5 ] and wanted to do something like this.

Create a new array where all elements below 3 will become negative and all elements above and equal to 3 will remain the same. if there is no element below 3 then it that case I have to throw an error.

So in this case new array will be [ -1, -2, 3, 4, 5].

How this can be done using lambda, filter?

This is my piece of code

```
AtomicInteger a = new AtomicInteger(0);

arrayList.stream()
    .map(data -> {
      if(data < 3) {a.getAndIncrement(); return -1 * data;}
      return data;
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

if(a.get() == 0) {
  throw  new RuntimeException();
}
```

Comment: I dont want to use Atomic Interger

Comment: But you did....

Comment: you don't need atomic integer here.. a simple int will also work.. its not a parallel stream.

Comment: What if initial array contains negative numbers? Your current code will change them into positive.

Comment: Should using AtomicBoolean instead of AtomicInteger to control the throw condition

Comment: Is there any other way to do it ? I want the best way to do it. I thought it can be done using filter but not sure how to do it in a single iteration

Comment: [Just use a `for`-loop and a `boolean` flag](https://ideone.com/qGdv5q)

Comment: Just a minor observation: in computing, it's important to use specific and precise language because minor misunderstandings can lead to major problems. You said you had an array but actually you have an ArrayList. They're two different things. Also you said "throw an error" when you meant "throw an exception". Error is a class of Throwable that is _not_ Exception.

Comment: There's nothing that says you _must_ use streams (assuming this is not a homework assignment). Just because streams exist does not mean they should replace every loop in a program. Use a loop if it's easier to implement, read, and maintain or if using a stream requires you to fight against the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of does what you require

```
    List<Integer> mappingResult = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
                                        .map(v -> v < 3 ? -v : v)
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    mappingResult.stream().filter(v -> v < 3).findAny().orElseThrow(() -> new InvalidStateException("No elements less than 3"));
```

Or this

```
    AtomicBoolean b=new AtomicBoolean();
    List<Integer> mappingResult = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
                                        .map(v -> v < 3 ? -v : v)
                                        .peek(v-> {if(v<3) b.set(true);})
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    if(!b.get()){
        throw new InvalidStateException("No elements less than 3");
    }
```

If you want negatives to still be negatives, use

```
.map(v -> v>0 && v < 3 ? -v : v)
```

As comment says, you can improve that even further (I assume that comments are aligned with original requirements)

```
    AtomicBoolean b = new AtomicBoolean();
    List<Integer> mappingResult = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
                                        .map(v -> {
                                            if (v > 0 && v < 3) {
                                                b.set(true);
                                                return -v;
                                            }
                                            return v;
                                        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    if (!b.get()) {
        throw new InvalidStateException("No elements less than 3");
    }
```

Comment: if the original list contains negative number, it would become positive

Comment: -10, -20, 3, 4, 5 will through error...

Comment: Sidenote: `peek` is **not** required to be executed

Comment: TBH op didnt care about negatives as he did exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You should compare `input` and `output`. If they are equal, throw an exception.

```
List<Integer> input = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
List<Integer> output = input.stream()
    .map(data -> data < 3 ? -data : data)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
if (output.equals(input))
    throw new RuntimeException();
```